# applying Update query with subquery is inserting zero if subquery returns null row

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $query1="UPDATE admin   SET  t_points=t_points+ (SELECT points from sites where url='$url') where username='$login_session'";
mysql_query($query1);
```

Query works fine if subquery  `SELECT points from sites where url='$url'` returns something.
When it returns nothing the previous value in t_points become null.

How to write more specific code so the value of t_point remain the same whether  subquery returns null?

Comment: This is probably vulnerable to severe [SQL injection problems](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should never be injecting raw variables into your queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is result query:

```
UPDATE admin 
SET  t_points = t_points + COALESCE( 
    SELECT points 
    FROM sites 
    WHERE url = '$url', 
    0
) 
WHERE username = '$login_session'
```

Whenever you doing math operations on NULL the result always is NULL, COALESCE returns first value if it isnt NULL, otherwise it returns second value

[COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Btw, before passing variables to a query, use mysql_real_escape_string on them:

```
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);
$login_session = mysql_real_escape_string($login_session);
```

But i advice you to use MySQL PDO, you can find some documentation here [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

To increase perfomance its better to separate UPDATE and SELECT queries (only works if SELECT query is same for every update query, like in the subject)
We can just pass result of the SELECT query to a variable and use this variable in UPDATE:

```
mysql_query("SET @points = COALESCE(
                 SELECT points
                 FROM sites
                 WHERE url = '$url', 
                 0
             )");
mysql_query("UPDATE admin 
             SET t_points = t_points + @points 
             WHERE username = '$login_session'");
```